# Indent second line of a bibliography and remove brackets

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I am writing a bibliography :

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\item Ahmad, S. \& Tresp, V . (1993), Some solutions to the missing feature 
 problem in \\ \hspace{2cm}  vision, in S. J. Hanson, J. D. Cowan \& C. L. 
Giles, eds, 'Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems', Vol. 5, 
Morgan Kaufmann, pp. 393–400.
\bibitem{}  Berthold, M. R. (1994), A time delay radial 
basisfunctionnetworkfor phonemerecognition, in 'Proceedings of International 
Conference on Neural Networks', Vol. 7, Orlando, pp. 4470–4473.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The result :
[image]
And what I would like to obtain :[image]
I want to indent the second and the third line and remove brackets.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you tells us with document class you are using.  The feature you are after is known as a hanging indent and is best set-up by styling the `thebibliography` environment.  Exactly how to that depends on its initial definition from the class file.

Comment: Hi  Andrew Swann I am a new bie studying LaTeX.

Comment: I am using Article document class

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is the default behaviour in the `article` class, so if you don't get that, you've done some changes we don't know about.

For removing the numbering, you can load the `natbib` package with the `authoryear` option. You need to format the `\bibitem`s as described in the `natbib` manual, i.e.

```
\bibitem[<author for citations>(<year>)]{<citation key>} ...
```

The stuff in the square brackets is used for formatting citations.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citep{ahmad93,berthold94}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Ahmad \& Tresp(1993)]{ahmad93} Ahmad, S. \& Tresp, V . (1993), Some solutions to the missing feature 
 problem in vision, in S. J. Hanson, J. D. Cowan \& C. L. 
Giles, eds, 'Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems', Vol. 5, 
Morgan Kaufmann, pp. 393--400.
\bibitem[Berthold(1994)]{berthold94}  Berthold, M. R. (1994), A time delay radial 
basisfunctionnetworkfor phonemerecognition, in 'Proceedings of International 
Conference on Neural Networks', Vol. 7, Orlando, pp. 4470--4473.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```