# How to remove number in \bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, bibitem

How can I remove the numbering in the bibliography?

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, b5paper]{scrbook} % http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{} Chatfield, T. (2012). \textit{How to Thrive in the Digital Age}. London: Macmillan.

\bibitem{} Diagne, S. B. (2018). \textit{Open to Reason: Muslim Philosophers in Conversation with the Western Tradition}. New York: Columbia University Press.

\bibitem{} Ihde, D (1993). \textit{Philosophy of Technology: An Introduction}. New York: Paragon.

\bibitem{} Newport, C. (2019). \textit{Digital Minimalism: Choosing a Focused Life in a Noisy World}. Penguin.

\bibitem{} Seldon, A., \& Abidoye, O. (2018). \textit{The Fourth Education Revolution: Will Artificial Intelligence Liberate or Infantilise Humanity?} The University of Buckingham Press.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368026/indent-second-line-of-a-bibliography-and-remove-brackets

Comment: Huge thanks! Problems solved.